# Invoicing and accounting software?

Tags: windows, finance, invoicing

I'm doing some work for a client of mine (upgrading systems, etc.), and they've asked me to simplify their billing process. It's a trucking dispatch company if that helps out. Here's the process now:

They receive original paperwork in the mail. When they get that, they total up the tonnage and the rate of pay, then invoice that in Quickbooks and pay the driver his cut, minus federal withholding, SS, and even things such as child support. They keep this information physically written down in a folder. Then they have to go to another company file in Quickbooks and bill the original company needing the freight moved.

In a perfect world, I would like to figure out how to have them enter the information (rates, tons, load numbers, etc.) only once. Obviously, drivers and the requesting companies don't need to know what my client is making from the deal.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've looked into BillQuick software and PaySim, but I'm not sure how well they'd integrate into their system.

Is there an existing software solution that could accomplish this task?

Comment: Software running local on a (windows?) client or is an (self-hosted) web application accepted? What do you think about cloud hosted services?

Answer (score 2):

#### [Xero](http://www.xero.com/)

We're in the process of switching to [Xero](http://www.xero.com/), a cloud-hosted system which can handle accounting, billing, inventory, payroll. One of their big things is minimising data entry by automatically importing & categorising from bank feeds. I've not used the [inventory features](http://www.xero.com/au/accounting-software/inventory/), but I think that would handle what you're after just looking at the documentation.

There's also a lot of plugins/addons that can provide additional features not included in the core.

Comment: +1 I support this answer. Another thing I love about Xero, is that you can use a mobile app, to take a photo of a receipt as you get it and it automatically upload it to your account in the cloud. No need to go crazy looking for receipts tax time.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved from Quickbooks into [FreeAgent](https://www.freeagent.com/?referrer=45ds4ylh). I believe it could support what you're saying (extra [add-ons](https://www.freeagent.com/developers/goodies/) can extend the functionality further more).

See: [Split a transaction for commission or charges deducted](https://www.freeagent.com/support/kb/banking/split-a-transaction-for-commission-or-charges-deducted/).

Answer (score 0):

A great accounting software that is useful for tracking expenses and invoices is Billbeez. All you have to do is e-mail over your bills/receipts and they give you a real time overview of your financials organized online.
https://billbeez.com/?utm_source=stack_exchange&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=traffic

(Disclosure: I work for Billbeez)

[image]

Comment: Please disclose any affiliation you have with Billbeez.  Thank you.